# Check property is present by property name

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to check is a string contains the name of a valid property of one of my entity class.

I've figured several keys but at the end i've been unable to make them work and even not sure what it the best practice to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i decided to go with

```
MyClass.metaClass.properties.find { it.name == params.searchedColName }
```

I think is little better solution than @Andrew von Dollen proposal since i avoid playing with the spring context ... feel that is more groovier this way.

Answer (score 1):

Every Grails domain object has an injected `domainClass` property which exposes a `persistentProperties` list.  You can access the list of properties in this way:

```
def o = new MyDomain()
o.domainClass.persistentProperties
```

You can also retrieve this list from the Spring application context, which avoids the need for a domain class instance. Among the  Spring beans created for each domain class (four beans for each domain) there is one that has the full name of your domain class with the suffix {{DomainClass}}. Assuming grailsApplication has been injected:

```
grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("MyDomainDomainClass").persistentProperties
```

Within the `persistentProperties` list, you can search for a property with a given name as follows:

```
persistentProperties.find { it.name == nameToSearchFor }
```

Comment: I think a list is not the best structure for searching ... may i need to loop across all elements checking for name? ... a map would be much more friendly. Documentation states that [Entity].properties responds with a Map but i think is wrong or something because i don't get that map.

Comment: Also you are using an instance while i'll prefer to use the class ... is there something for doing this checking using metaclass or something like this?

Comment: I find a similar solution but think that is a bit simpler since doesnt involve playing with spring context and maybe more correct from groovy pov. What do you think?